# Can you identify that flower?

Tags: identification, flowers

Can you identify that flower?? (exact cultivar)

Height: 2.5m Spread: 0.7m Sunny position. One plant has multiple flowers. The pictured two belong to the same plant! (even though they are little different)

[image]

Comment: Height and spread? foliage? If you want an exact cultivar these are  essential to know, otherwise its an educated guess...

Comment: Added something @bamboo

Comment: 2.5m? over 8 feet?

Comment: Yes. Very tall. Even my neighbour seems not to like the height. Perhaps it is so tall because this is a group of closely planted plants of the same kind. @bamboo

Comment: Well its a Helianthus annuus, and I've found one similar, but unfortunately, its only name on the American link is 'Red Sunflower' which isn't much use... it is tall though, over 6 feet...the other thing is,the colour on these can change over a day or two - they might get darker or lighter, so the best ID is always with a freshly opened flower. There are hundreds of varieties, but fewer really tall ones.

Comment: Is it possible / common in sunflowers to have different flowers, on the same plant? @bamboo

Comment: Usually its because one flower is older than another - that's the colour change I'm talking about... plus random variations in each flower in the newer, coloured varieties (as opposed to the basic yellow) aren't that unusual.

Comment: This was probably packaged under some sort of name like Autumn Beauty mix or similar. You'll notice volunteers in subsequent years that get more and more yellow eventually looking like a small yellow typical sunflower.